# Proving the isomorphism $A \otimes B \cong B\otimes A$ of the tensor products of abelian groups $A,B$ given the definition by the quotient groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-groups

> For two Abelian groups $A$ and $B$ we define their tensor product
> $A\otimes B$ as the quotient of the free Abelian group on the set of
> formal generators $\{a \otimes b \mid a \in A; b \in B\}$ by the
> subgroup generated by elements of the form $$a_1 \otimes b + a_2
>  \otimes b − (a_1 + a_2) \otimes b$$ and $$a\otimes b_1 +a\otimes b_2
>  −a\otimes(b_1 +b_2).$$ By abuse of notation we write $a\otimes b$ for
> the corresponding element in the quotient $A \otimes B.$

I'd like to prove that $A\otimes B \cong B\otimes A$. Now my first thought was using the map $$a\otimes b \mapsto b \otimes a$$

Now it's obvious this is compatible with the relations. But I don't know how the quotients $A\otimes B$ and $B\otimes A$ become isomorphic. According to the solution, "it descends to the quotients", but I don't know how. Could someone please elaborate how we precisely get the isomorphism??

Comment: "Descends to the quotients" means that there is an induced map $A\otimes B\to B\otimes A, [a\otimes b]\mapsto [b\otimes a]$ on equivalence classes. This is a consequence of it being compatible with the relations, by the universal property of quotients. You could appeal to the first isomorphism theorem to see it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting it to be somehow related to the universal property of quotients and the first isomorphism theorem, but i couldn't figure out how. The first isomorphism theorem tells me that for a surjective homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to H$ the quotient $G/\operatorname{ker} \varphi$ is isomorphic to $H$. How can i make use of it in this case? If i am not mistaken, i need to find a surjective map from $\{a\otimes b\}$ to the quotient $B\otimes A$?

Comment: are the relations by any means the generating elements of the kernel? I am not too experienced with presentations of groups.

Comment: Explicitly, compose the swap map with the quotient projection to $B\otimes A$ - you should see that this composition is surjective. Check what the kernel is, and you should find that it's exactly the subgroup generated by the given relations (in particular, the answer to your last question is yes).

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Alex!

Comment: @Zest Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Alex's comment helped me where i was stuck. I haven't fully understood your proposed solution yet, i need to work through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\widetilde{\otimes} B$ denote the free abelian group on symbols $a\otimes b$. We have, by the universal property of free abelian groups, a group homomorphism $\tilde{f}:A\widetilde{\otimes} B \to B\widetilde{\otimes} A$, given on generators by $a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$.

Let $I$ be subgroup in $A\widetilde{\otimes} B$ generated by expressions $a_1 \otimes b + a_2
 \otimes b − (a_1 + a_2) \otimes b$ and $a\otimes b_1 +a\otimes b_2
 −a\otimes(b_1 +b_2)$,  with $a,a_i\in A,b\in B$. Define the subgroup $J\subset B\tilde{\otimes} A$ in a similar way.

As you noted, if $x\in I$ then $\tilde{f}(x)\in J$, so $\tilde{f}$ induces  a homomorphism $$f:A\otimes B = A\widetilde{\otimes}B/I\to B\widetilde{\otimes}A/J= B\otimes A,$$
given by $f(x+I)=\tilde{f}(x)+J$.

In a similar way, you have a homomorphism $g$ in the other direction, given by $g(y+J)=\tilde{g}(y)+I$.

It remains to check that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other. That's clear, as on generators $$(g\circ f)(a\otimes b +I)=g(b\otimes a +J)=a\otimes b +I.$$
The same for $f\circ g$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use more convenient notations: in the free abelian group $\mathbf Z^{(X)}$ generated by a set $X$, I'll denote $[x]$ the element $e_x$, i.e. the map which sends $x$ to $1$ and any $x'\ne x$ to $0$.

This being said, you have a bijective map from $\mathbf Z^{(A\times B)}$ to $\mathbf Z^{(B\times A)}$, which sends $[(a,b)]$ to $[(b,a)]$. This map sends generators of the relations defining the tensor product in the first free group, namely $[(a_1,b)]+[(a_2,b)]-[(a_1+a_2,b)]$ onto the generators of the relations defining the tensor product in the second free group,  $[(b,a_1)]+[(b,a_2)]-[(b,a_1+a_2)]$, hence the subgroup  $R_{A\times B}$ generated by the first set onto the subgroup $R_{B\times A}$ generated by the second group.

Therefore we have a commutative diagram of abelian groups
\begin{alignat}{5}
0\longrightarrow &R_{A\times B}\hookrightarrow&&\mathbf Z^{A\times B}\longrightarrow A\otimes B\longrightarrow 0 \\
&\quad\downarrow&&\enspace\downarrow\\
0\longrightarrow &R_{B\times A}\hookrightarrow&&\mathbf Z^{A\times B}\longrightarrow B\otimes A\longrightarrow 0 
\end{alignat}
which induces a morphism from $A\otimes B$ to $B\otimes A$ by the universal property of kernels. As the the two vertical maps are group isomorphisms, the induced morphism  is an isomorphism too.